# Gradle Build Failed. Gradle can't see resources

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.

   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.

     Required by:

         project :launcher

      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.

         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.

            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.

               > dl.google.com

      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.

         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.

            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom'.

               > jcenter.bintray.com

* Try:

Run with —stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with —info or —debug option to get more log output. Run with —scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I am using Unity 2021.3.16f1

I have tried different ways to solve the problem. I even resorted to formatting the device, but without result

Comment: Did you try the suggested commands ? They would probably show more details /messages on the errors.

Comment: Jcenter repo is not suported now. Try to remove it from gradle file or replace for mavenCentral, for example.

Comment: Where is this file?